# Linear Algebra Column and Null Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How would you do a double containment proof of $\mathrm{Nul}(A)=\mathrm{Col}(A-I)$, where $I$ is an identity matrix and $A$ is a square matrix, such that $A^2=A$?

Comment: Duplicate of this. Classmates? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809474/when-a-matrix-m-equals-m2-why-is-this-property-true/

Comment: Ah, found this thread too. Thank you. But I still don't fully understand how the complete proof would look like: specifically, how do you show that Nul(A) is a subspace of Col(A-I) and vice versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a matrix, $M$ equals $M^2$, why is this property true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809474/when-a-matrix-m-equals-m2-why-is-this-property-true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$\supseteq$": Take a vector $v \in Col(A-I)$. You want to show $Av =0$. Since $v \in Col(A-I)$ there exists a vector $x$ such that $(A - I)x = v$. This gives you $v = Ax - x$. What is $Av$ ?

"$\subseteq$": Take a vector $v \in Nul(A)$. You want to show there is a vector $x$ such that $(A-I)x = v$. Since $v \in Nul(A)$, we have $Av =0$ and adding $-v$ to both sides results in $$(A-I)v = Av - v = 0 - v = -v$$ Can you see what $x$ should be ?

Comment: Av= A(Ax-x)=(A^2)x-Ax=0? which proves that column space of A is subspace of the null space of A, right?

Comment: yes that's correct, good job!

Comment: this may be a dumb question but can v be a subspace of itself? since we established that v=Nul(A) and that it's an element of Col(A-I)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. We've taken a $v$ *in* $Col(A-I)$ and established that $v$ is *in* $Nul(A)$, not equal to $Nul(A)$.

Comment: Oh I understand now, thank you! And would the answer to your second question be that x should be -v? If x=-v, what does that show us?

Comment: If $x = -v$, then what is $(A-I)x$ ? and what does that mean?

Comment: Means that -v is an element of Col(A-I), right?

Answer (score 1):

$x \in Null(A) \iff Ax=0 \iff (A-I)x=-x \iff -x \in Col(A-I) \iff x \in Col(A-I) $.